# Spying on window.open in angular / jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a single component in Angular 4 with a link in its html template and I would like to test if clicking on the link calls window.open.

For the purposes of this question my component is emty:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-voter',
templateUrl: './voter.component.html',
})
export class VoterComponent {}
```

The template of the component:

```
<div class="voter">
  <a href="http://index.hu/" class="index-hu">Index</a>
</div>
```

My test case:

```
  it('should open the given link when clicked on it', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(window, 'open').and.callThrough();
    const link = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.index-hu'));

    link.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This test case fails, but I have no idea why.

Comment: A link click does not use `window.open` I assume.

Comment: What does it use?

Comment: No JavaScript at all.

Comment: You should probably just check that the url has changed or that some part of the ui has changed after the click.

Comment: Since <a> is not a directive and doesn't call window.open, what's the purpose of testing a behaviour that is inherent in all browsers?